# How to write .htaccess so that https is on for subpages only but not the home page

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

The root of my domain successfully redirects to a subdirectory, meaning `example.com` redirects to `example.com/abc`.

`example.com` has no WordPress install.

`example.com/abc` has its own WordPress install.

The homepage on `http://example.com/abc` is not HTTPS and I don't want it to be, however, I do want all the sub-pages to be HTTPS (eg. `https://example.com/abc/xyz` or `https://example.com/abc/thistoo`)

My current `.htaccess` file is the standard WordPress stuff...

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /abc/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've checked and tried many other solutions that I've found here but so far no joy.

p.s. I know to re-save permalinks after making changes like this to the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: "`example.com` redirects to `example.com/abc`" - where are you performing this redirect? "The homepage on `http://example.com/abc`" - presumably you mean `http://example.com/abc/` (with a trailing slash)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your `.htaccess` file is located in the `/abc` subdirectory? In which case you can do something like the following to force HTTPS on all sub-pages, except the homepage:

This needs to go at the very top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule !^(index\.php)?$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

This assumes that the SSL cert is installed directly on your application server.

The *negated* `RewriteRule` *pattern* `!^(index\.php)?$` only matches non-empty (or not `index.php`) URL-paths, so this excludes the homepage.

Change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK, to avoid caching issues. Clear your browser cache before testing.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteBase /abc/
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /abc/index.php [L]
> ```

Since you have set the `RewriteBase` directive, you can remove the directory-prefix from the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (this is what the `RewriteBase` directive does):

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

However, since your `.htaccess` file is in the `/abc` subdirectory, then you don't actually need the `RewriteBase` directive or the directory-prefix.

Comment: That has worked perfectly, MrWhite. Thank you so much.